# How many Hogwarts students changed House from book to film?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, adaptation-comparison, sorting-hat

The only example I can think of is **Padma Patil**: Ravenclaw in the books, Gryffindor in the films.

Were there any other Hogwarts students who were in one House in the books but in a different one in the film adaptations? If so, who were they?

Comment: Ah Padma Patil, the Gryffinclaw...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No** at least not that I have found so far.

After comparing the Lexicon and the Character listings from each film they do not seem to have had any other house changes. They did however omit a lot of characters from being in the films whilst at the same time included a lot of characters who were never mentioned in the books. As well as have a lot of uncredited (insert house name here) students floating around I would presume as filler content.

Disclaimer: I think to fully compare the two one would have to study the films for any discrepancies with the clothing throughout for the students.

Comment: Not to mention the number of students who changed years (Cho Chang, Katie Bell and, it seems, Romilda Vane). But I can't find anyone who changed houses either

Comment: Totally @Au101 not to mention as well the number of characters who weren't around for a few years and suddenly became present in the right year...

Comment: And Flitwick's massive transformation ... :P

Comment: @Au101 They could have at least addressed that with like Flitwick Sr & Jr or something. It's so confusing if you don't know about it.

Comment: @Au101 Students who changed years? That'd make a great followup question!