# How can Cho Chang be afraid to fail her O.W.L.s if she's a year ahead?

Tags: harry-potter

In numerous Harry Potter books, Cho Chang is described as a year older than Harry. And, in OotP, Harry and the other 5th years are taking their O.W.L.s. Then why did Hermione say in the movie, "And she's so frightened that she'll fail her O.W.L.s because she's so worried about everything else"? She should have completed her O.W.L.s and gotten her results!

Comment: A physical year older does not always mean a class year older. Herminone herself was "a year older" than Harry. Harry had just turned 11 when he started Hogwarts, while Hermione turned 12 shortly after the school year began.

Answer (score 19):

### In the films, Cho Chang is in Harry's year

We see in a number of shots in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 2* that Cho Chang is a student at Hogwarts who is wearing a school uniform.

[image]
[image]

Thus she is a 7th year student in *Deathly Hallows*.

This is different from the books where she has already graduated by the time of *Deathly Hallows* (and came to the Battle of Hogwarts [because she received the Dumbledore's Army signal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39082/13217) and traveled there).

In general, the movies and the books sometimes have contradictory canon. Because something happens in the films doesn't mean that's how it happens in the books.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106361/4918 "How many Hogwarts students changed year from book to film?"